# Как сделать, чтоб sqrt не округлял значение? Входные данные: -999 -999 999 999

Tags: c++

Как сделать, чтоб sqrt не округлял значение? Входные данные: -999 -999 999 999

```
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>


using namespace std;

ifstream in("input.txt");
ofstream out("output.txt");

int main()
{
    int inf[4];
    long double answer;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        in >> inf[i];

    answer = sqrt(pow(inf[0] - inf[2], 2) + pow(inf[1] - inf[3], 2));
    out << answer;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: а условие то какое , Или ссылка на задачу? pow медленная. она тут не нужна, так как разность в степени 2 это **(inf[0] - inf[2]) * (inf[0] - inf[2])**  . да и цикл не нужен **in >> inf[0] >> inf[1]>> inf[2]>> inf[3];**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего, вы путаете, **кто** округляет...

При выводе по умолчанию выводятся 6 знаков.

```
out << setprecision(16) << answer << "\n";
```

изменит ваше мнение о работе `sqrt`...

Comment: Спасибо, буду знать...

Comment: Если вопрос решен - закрывайте, приняв ответ...